# Speed up for-loop that creates a new column using .loc into a faster method?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, list-comprehension

I've been using the below method to assign values to a new column based on each row meeting multiple criteria from multiple lists. It works for small dfs...but once I'm working with bigger data, it takes forever.

```
for i, j, k in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    df.loc[((df['foo'] == i) & (df['bar'] == j)),'new_column'] = k
```

Example data:

```
list1 = ['a', 'a', 'e', 'f', 'c']
list2 = [3, 4, 5, 3, 2]
list3 = ['yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'orange', 'black']

df = pd.dataframe({'foo': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'c'], 
                   'bar': [3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 3, 2]})
```

So essentially for the new column, I need:

- 1st row tagged as yellow (because list1=a & list2=3)
- 3rd row tagged as black (because list1=c & list2=2)
- 5th row tagged as blue (because list1=e & list2=5)
- 6th row tagged as orange (because list1=f & list2=3)
- 7th row tagged as black (because list1=c & list2=2)

All of the lists are the same length. I've scoured Stack for better options, and so I know that one option is list comprehension (or others), but unsure how to combine that with .loc and creating a new column.

Thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: How are the sizes of the `list*` variables?

Comment: All of the lists are the same length (they're just 3 columns from a different df). :)

Comment: Yeah, I meant which is the length of `list1` for example? I'm trying to see how many loops you need to run and how many combinations you'll have.

Comment: Aye...97,381 in each list.

Comment: Maybe you can show the example dataframe and then illustrating what you have done and what you want that will get accurate answers, maybe you don't require for loop at all as  it can e done using pandas internal functions.

Comment: Updated to show example data and enhanced description--thank you.

Comment: The code is incorrect. Please declare lists properly. For strings use `"` quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is use `zip` with `DataFrame` costructor, so possible use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(zip(list1, list2, list3), columns=['foo','bar','new_column'])
print (df1)
  foo  bar new_column
0   a    3     yellow
1   a    4      green
2   e    5       blue
3   f    3     purple
4   c    2     orange

df = df.merge(df1, how='left', on=['foo','bar'])
print (df)
  foo  bar new_column
0   a    3     yellow
1   b    2        NaN
2   c    2     orange
3   d    4        NaN
4   e    5       blue
5   f    3     purple
6   c    2     orange
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to achieve the equivalent of a join operation here. The following should give you the same result and uses dataframe operations so will likely be faster than looping over the lists.

(I removed 'purple' from your example)

```py
list3 = ['yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'black']
```

Build a dataframe from your lists and join on the criteria (foo = i & bar = j):

```
joiner = pd.DataFrame({"i": list1, "j": list2, "k": list3})
df.join(joiner.set_index(["i", "j"]), on=["foo", "bar"])
```

Giving:

```
  foo  bar       k
0   a    3  yellow
1   b    2     NaN
2   c    2   black
3   d    4     NaN
4   e    5    blue
5   f    3  orange
6   c    2   black
```

Note that if you have duplicate matches there will be a repeated (foo, bar) row for each (i, j) match. You'll need to de-duplicate the dataframe to get the same results as your loop code, and the joined dataframe could become quite large. I'm guessing though that since your code would always overwrite any duplicate this is not common?